# PowerApps failure starting on April 7th after Upgrade of App on IOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, sharepoint-online, powerapps

We used a PowerApps application daily on many different devices since Dec 17 without any issues and now after getting an update of Powerapps on April 7th on IOS/Android the app fails to work.

The app takes photos, adds some attributes and sends it off to SharePoint/Flow. This is done by using a customer connector.

Now starting April 7, when you trigger the upload to the connector, the following error message shows

> Contract Failure: Construction of a PABinary should always result in a valid instance.

If we test the connector manually it works fine, so does the app when used in the browser on a Windows machine. So the error must be in the app itself.

Any ideas how to debug this or what could be causing this? Devices with the "old" Powerapp version still work fine. Help from Microsoft is appreciated ;-)

Comment: can you share a session id? I am from the PowerApps team and I am trying to see if we can help with more things. Also, the forum will be the best place to post about such issues.

Comment: just took it from my Android 6.0.1, Sitzungs-ID: 42fb4293-5b4b-4067-8298-dfec7f160f24 Powerapps version 3.18042.25 - many thanks, hope this is what you want.........one thing I'm using multiple apps with the same mechanism, all of the fail with the same error starting April 7

Comment: were you able to figure out something? my customers are unable to work - bad and sad for my and their business...

Comment: Hi Chris, we need some additional information that will require going through the PowerApps support channel. Can you please create a support ticket by going to https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/support/ and using the “Create support ticket” button at the bottom of the page? Thanks!

Comment: it's done - see 118041718013834

Comment: any update on this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/On-Android-user-gets-error-uploading-photos-via-a-flow/m-p/110318#M39768